# C# how to add usercontrols dynamically in tabPage

Tags: c#

I do not know how to add usercontrol..

My code and control are below

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        test = new test[index];
        for (int i = 0; i < test.Length; i++)
        {
            test[i] = new RecorderGenerator.test();
            test[i].Location = new Point(0, i * 20);
            test[i].Size = new Size(100, 10);
            test[i].TabIndex = i;
            test[i].BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            test[i].AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.None;
            test[i].Visible = true;
            this.tabPage1.Controls.Add(test[i]);
        }

        index++;
    }
```

I try to add other controls(e.g textbox) and It is possible.

but I can not add control that is made by me

Comment: Whats the problem/error? Also, `new RecorderGenerator.test()` looks suspicious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Make sure your control behaves as any other control and you can add it manually in Visual Studio
2. Add your control manually to the tab page
3. Inspect the automatically generated code
4. Copy this code (and modify accordingly)